# Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, psql, flyway

I reinstalled Postgre with psql.
Now I have problems with application start.
I grant the roles and privileges to roles.
Added users with privileges to the database.
And I still have problem like in topic title.

```
Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"
```

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for table schema_version
```

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"
```

P.S.
Entire application was working on the same dump.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that user is missing privileges on schema. Try this:

```
   grant all privileges on schema public to my_app_user;
```

Where *my_app_user* is the user used in application to connect to database.